# How to filter array and create new array with specific object keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an array with objects and in each object there is an "items" array. My goal is to combine these "items" into one array.

**Goal / Expected Output**

```
[
   { id: 'SUV' },
   { id: 'Compact' },
   { id: 'Gasoline' },
   { id: 'Hybrid' }
]
```

**Sample Array**

```
[
{
  "id":"carType",
  "items":[
     {
        "id":"SUV"
     },
     {
        "id":"Compact"
     }
  ]
},
{
  "id":"fuelType",
  "items":[
     {
        "id":"Gasoline"
     },
     {
        "id":"Hybrid"
     }
  ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use `Array#flatMap`.

```js
const data = [{"id":"carType","items":[{"id":"SUV"},{"id":"Compact"}]},{"id":"fuelType","items":[{"id":"Gasoline"},{"id":"Hybrid"}]}];

const r = data.flatMap(({ items }) => items);

console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 3):

A one-liner in vanilla JS (earlier than EMCAScript 2019, flatMap is not available, so in case of that...)

```
[].concat(...arr.map(elt => elt.items))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
newArr = []
for (let i = 0;i<arr.length;i++) {
  for (let ii = 0;ii<arr[i].items.length;ii++) {
    newArr.push(arr[i].items[ii].id)
  }
}
console.log(newArr)
```